# Formatting JSON for output with Java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{
    "Person":{
        "Name":"Johnny Doe",
        "Age":30,
        "Gender":"Female",
        "Address":{
            "Number":10,
            "Line1":"Downing Street",
            "City":"London",
            "Country":"UK"
        },
        "PhoneNumbers":{
            "Number":"999"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I iterate through the data so I can produce a nice, formatted output that looks like this?

```
Person
    Name: Johnny Doe
    Age: 30
    Gender: Female
    Address
        Number: 10
        Line1: Downing Street
        City: London
        Country: UK
    PhoneNumbers
        Number: 999
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Try the Json-Simple library, or parse it manually.

Comment: I tried to use Gson, but didn't get very far. I don't know how to do much in Java, but it's task I have been given to do.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this link](http://www.json.org/java/) to find different JSON parsers available in java. You could select one and use that to parse the json into some sort of map and then iterate through to print the conten the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

JSONObject has a toString method which output a string like your first representation.
See doc : http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#toString%28int%29

You can adjust indentation.

Then, you will just have to delete (via replace) '{', '}', ',', and '"' characters.

Apolo